# Firefox vs 11.0 Issue with Cache

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox, https

I am having an issue with Firefox storing cache, even though I explicitly state not to. I have this in my code for .jsp, .html, and template.html

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0" />
   <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
   <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00 GMT" />
</head>
```

While it seems to be making a difference, as I can navigate away from the page, and (sometimes) it will bring me to my login page, logging out and back in produce errors. 
     [RPC Fault faultString="login required before authorization can proceed."
But then it will bring me through to my homepage apparently logged in, but without any data.

I don't understand this because it works fine in IE, and also this is https, so I don't see why any cache is ever getting stored anyway. Please help!

Also, I cannot ask users to disable browser history, even though this seems to "fix" the issue.

I tried the following to change the HTTP header, but I am  not sure if this is the correct way because it didnt' work. I put this at the top of my .jsp.

```
 <%
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
 response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
 response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
 %>
```

Comment: This sounds more like a cookie issue than a cache issue.

Comment: Kinda makes sense, but isn't an SSL connection supposed to disable cookies too, or do I have to state in my code not to store cookies? If so, how?

Comment: Nevermind. I tried just deleting cookies and just deleting cache, and it only worked when I deleted cache.

Comment: I tested the application, and there were cache files when I used Firefox.

Comment: Perhaps [this question may help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers). Note bobince's answer, wherein he points out that it's better to do this with HTTP headers instead of `<meta>` tags.

Comment: There's a Firefox add-on called [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) that will show you lots of information about each HTTP transaction. That might help diagnose problems setting your headers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am behind an intranet with this application, and cannot use add-ons. I did notice that it was not getting rid of the cache, like it should have been.